# How to make a generic Func<TEntity, bool>?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, lambda

I'm trying make a generic query for my Dao Entity Framework context. Like this:

```
public List<TEntity> Buscar(Func<TEntity, bool> predicate)
{
    return SelectAll().Where(predicate).AsQueryable().ToList();
}
public List<TEntity> SelectAll()
{
    return DbContexto.Set<TEntity>().ToList();
}
```

But I cant find how call the method because as I don't know the entity, then the lambda expression does not accept the member that I try to pass. If I try this:

```
public List<TEnt> Buscar()
{            
    return AutoMapperConfig.Mapper.Map<List<TEntEF>, List<TEnt>>(Dao.Buscar(x => x.ID == 1 ));
}
```

I have na error in "x.ID" that say:"TEntEF" does not contain a definition for "ID" and could not find any "ID" extension method that accepts a first argument of type "TEntEF" (is there a usage directive or assembly reference missing?)

And if I try like this:

```
public List<TEnt> Buscar()
{
    Func<PESSOAS, bool> pred = delegate (PESSOAS item)
    {
        return item.ID == 2;
    };

    return AutoMapperConfig.Mapper.Map<List<TEntEF>, List<TEnt>>(Dao.Buscar(pred));
}
```

I have na error in "(pred)" that say: Can not convert from "`System.Func<EFBcostedSQL.PESSOAS, BOOL>`" to "`System.Func<TEntEF, bool>`"

I do not know any other way ... Any idea how I can solve this?

---**Add later**-------------------------------------------------
I do not want to do a base class or Interface, because I'm working with DataBase First and if I have to extend all partial classes, it does not make sense. Besides that my base class has no way to have the properties of all classes and I want to be able to use any property.

And now I understanding that there is no possible, I try this because I have an intermediate layer so that my View layer does not see my Context layer. And in this intermediary layer I did not want to make a class for each entity, only one general, that would work for all entities in my context.

Comment: Your last two code examples don't make sense: Your methods have a `predicate` parameter but never use it.

Comment: 1) Looks like you're using EF, so you need `Expression<Func<TEnt, bool>>`, not just func
2) You can specify an interface or a base class that all `TEnt` would inherit from.

Comment: As an aside, the `Buscar` method called `SelectAll` which drags your entire database table into memory before querying it - please don't get into that habit.

Comment: Thanks @Heinzi for yu atention. Just ignore (I remove in last edit) I'm trying to find just how to mount this predicate.

Comment: @zaitsman.Yes You got the idea. But I do not want to do this, since I'm working with DataBase First and if I have to extend all partial classes, it does not make sense. Besides that my base class has no way to have the properties of all classes and I want to be able to use any property.

Comment: @ylax my DbContexto is public GPSdEntities DbContexto { get; set; } = new GPSdEntities();  and GPSdEntities it's a auto genrate context, make by Databae First.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you filter on a **specific** entity type (PESSOAS), you need to return that specific type instead of a generic `TEnt`:

```
public List<PESSOAS> GetPessoasWithID2()
{
    Func<PESSOAS, bool> pred = delegate (PESSOAS item)
    {
        return item.ID == 2;
    };

    return Dao.Buscar(pred);
}
```

which can, of course, be shortened to

```
public List<PESSOAS> GetPessoasWithID2()
{
    return Dao.Buscar<PESSOAS>(item => item.ID == 2);
}
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks Heizi. Then the only solve is use in especific class to PESSOAS? It's work to me, realy thanks. But if you have any ideia about use in generit type, that would be perfect.

Comment: @AlamEstudent: How would "filtering on ID 2" make sense with a generic type?

Comment: This is just an example. It could be anything: ID, NAME, SANITUINE TYPE, MARK, etc.

Comment: Then you alread have it: `Dao.Buscar<X>(Y)` is your generic method and when you use it, you replace: X with the concrete type and Y with the concrete filter (Name, Mark, whatever).

Answer (score 0):

Your Entities must implement common interface with ID property
For example:

```
public interface IHasId<T> where T: struct
{
        T ID { get; set; }
}

public class PESSOAS: IHasId<int>
{
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

And use it as:

```
Func<PESSOAS, bool>
```

Comment: Realy its the only solve? You got the idea. But I do not want to do this, since I'm working with DataBase First and if I have to extend all partial classes, to inherit the interface, it does not make sense. Besides that my base class has no way to have the properties of all classes and I want to be able to use any property

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for? Not 100% sure I understood the question. Let me know if I'm off the mark...

```
class Customer
{
    [Key]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
class Order
{
    [Key]
    public int OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
}

class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext()
    {
        //connect MyContext to some data source here

        Customers.Add(new Customer { Name = "John" });
        Customers.Add(new Customer { Name = "Jacob" });
        Customers.Add(new Customer { Name = "Hannah" });
    }
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }

    public IQueryable<TEntity> Buscar<TEntity>(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate) 
        where TEntity : class
    {
        return this.Set<TEntity>().Where(predicate).AsQueryable<TEntity>();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyContext _context = new MyContext();
        IQueryable<Customer> _customers = _context.Buscar<Customer>(c=>c.Name.StartsWith("J"));
        foreach(Customer cust in _customers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Customer Name=" + cust.Name);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes @ylax, thanks. The only problem I have, and I'm sorry, because I understand that there is no possible, I wanted to call it with generic T like IQueryable <T> _customers = _context.search <T> (c => c.Name.StartsWith ("J"));. That's why I have an intermediate layer so that my View layer does not see my Context layer. And in this intermediary layer I did not want to make a class for each entity, only one general, that would work for all entities in my context.

Comment: At some point, you have to tell your context what type of entity you're searching for. Perhaps there's a way to infer the type in your calling code? If so, you can pass a type instead of a generic parameter.